pthead_cond_wait wake up thread case crash
I use an ConcurrentQueue in my project.But sometimes I meet crash caused by this ConcurrentQueue.I do not have any idea about this crash so I want to get some help.This code show my ConcurrentQueue
#include <pthread.h>
#include <queue>

template <typename Data>
class ConcurrentQueue {
private:
    std::queue<Data> the_queue;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t condition;

public:
    ConcurrentQueue() {
        this->mutext = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
        this->condition = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
    }

    ~ConcurrentQueue() {}

    void Push(Data &data) {
        pthread_mutext_lock(&this->mutext);
        this->the_queue.push(data);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&this->mutext);
        pthead_cond_signal(&this->condition);
    }

    void wait_and_pop(Data& poped_value) {
        pthead_mutex_lock(&this->mutext);
        while (this->the_queue.empty()){
            pthead_cond_wait(&this->condition,&this->mutext);
        }
        poped_value = this->the_queue.front();
        this->the_queue.pop();
        pthead_mutex_unlock(&this->mutext);
    }
};


the crash happened at "poped_value = this->the_queue.front();" I guess that crash is caused by the_queue empty.But I think the_queue could not be empty, because before use the_queue front api,I have checked the_queue is empty or not.Also the_queue could not poped by other threads when I checked it's empty status.If other threads want to pop the queue,it must get the lock.However,the threads which checked the lock must have the lock so other threads could not get the lock.

Is this your actual code? The typos in PTHRED_MUTEXT_INITIALIZER suggest either it isn't, or the compiler is giving you warnings that you're ignoring. Fix the compile warnings and/or post your actual code!

sorry,I commit the actual code again

What's mutext, and how, if  at all, is it related to mutex?

Apart from the typo, I don't see anything immediately wrong with the code shown. The problem likely lies in the code not shown; in the code that uses ConcurrentQueue. Prepare a [mcve].

Does this actually compile?  PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER and PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER expand to initializers.  You can use them in definitions of mutexes and condition variables, respectively, to specify their initial values, but they are not (generally) assignable.  In your constructor, you should be using the pthread_mutex_init() and pthread_cond_init() functions to initialize the instance's existing mutex and condition variable.  And you should be destroying them with their respective *_destroy() functions in the destructor.

That's fantasy code. Please post actual unedited code that you have compiled.
